# python - How to use python call function in pyx file

Tags: python, cython

I am new to cython.

Now, I am trying to import standard c library and define a simple function in pyx file:

```
from libc.math cimport sin

cdef double f(double x):
    return sin(x*x)
```

I compiled with this file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("demo",
              ["demo.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"]) # Unix-like specific
]

setup(
  name = "Demos",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

and generate a library called demo.so
now I am trying to call this "f" function in a python file:

```
import demo
print demo.f(2)
```

The compiler said,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Does anyone know, how can I call the function in pyx file? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions defined with `cdef` *cannot* be accessed from python. You can write them and use them inside the cython code but they cannot be exposed.

If you want to expose a function either define it with `def`, or define it using `cpdef`.

Using `def` you'll create a normal python function, which means using that function in the cython code might require more conversions then using `cdef` (and hence more overhead).

Using `cpdef` cython will generate *two* functions. One is *exactly* the function that would be defined using `cdef` and it will also create a python function that acts as a wrapper for this function. The cython code will use the pure-C version of the function, thus reducing the overhead, and the library will expose the wrapper.